# Chaining enumerators that yield multiple arguments

Tags: ruby, block, enumerators

I'm trying to figure out how Ruby handles chaining enumerators that yield multiple arguments. Take a look at this snippet:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

a.each_with_index.select{|pr| p pr}
# prints:
# ["a", 0]
# ["b", 1]
# ["c", 2]

a.each_with_index.map{|pr| p pr}
# prints:
# "a"
# "b"
# "c"
```

Why does `select` yield the arguments as an array, whereas `map` yields them as two separate arguments?

Comment: Very interesting. It's a very rarely seen high quality Ruby question asked by a newcomer recently. You are a wise man.

Comment: I've sent mail about this issue to ruby-core, and I'll update here when I hear back. [link](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/51614)

Comment: The best is to sign up to http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/, I also posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discourse so far, it follows that we can analyze the source code, but we do not know the whys. Ruby core team is relatively very responsive. I recommend you to sign in at http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/ and post a bug report there. They will surely look at this issue at most within a few weeks, and you can probably expect it corrected in the next minor version of Ruby. (That is, unless there is a design rationale unknown to us to keep things as they are.)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
a.each_with_index.map{|pr,last| p "pr: #{pr} last: #{last}"}
```

`map` is automatically deconstructing the values passed to it. The next question is *why* is it doing this deconstruction and `select` isn't?

If you look at [the source given on the Rdoc page for Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) they're virtually identical, `select` only differs in that it does a test on the value yielded. There must be something happening elsewhere.

If we look at the [Rubinius source](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable19.rb#L37) (mainly because I'm better with Ruby than C;) for `map` (aliased from `collect`) it shows us:

```
each do |*o|
```

so it's splatting the arguments on the way through, whereas [select](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable.rb#L236) (aliased from `find_all`) does not:

```
each do
```

again, the design decision as to *why* is beyond me. You'll have to find out who wrote it, maybe ask Matz :)

---

I should add, looking at the Rubinius source again, `map` actual splats on `each` *and* on `yield`, I don't understand why you'd do both when only the yield splat is needed:

```
  each do |*o|
    ary << yield(*o)
  end
```

whereas `select` doesn't.

```
each do
  o = Rubinius.single_block_arg
  ary << o if yield(o)
end
```

Comment: That's what i figured. I'm still interested in the _why_ -- and whether there's any documentation on which methods use which technique. Any idea what the best way to get in touch with Matz/the core ruby devs is?

Comment: I will post this as a regular answer.

Comment: @BenWeissmann then the answer Boris gave is most helpful. I'd suggest the way right now to find out which methods use which technique is either to try a desconstruction using a pattern in IRB (e.g. `do |(a,b)|`…) or look at the Rubinius source (as it's supposed to match the MRI implementation) and see if `yield` takes a splat. The link I gave above will take you to the right place, any of kernel/common/xxx will be the core. You could always ask the Rubinius contributors in #rubinius on Freenode, since they reimplemented it.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the MRI source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7ea675732ac1dac72f07756498706678d8725719/enum.c), it seems like the iterator used in `select` splats its arguments coming in, but `map` does not and passes them unpacked; the block in your latter case silently ignores the other arguments.

The iterator used in `select`:

```
static VALUE
find_all_i(VALUE i, VALUE ary, int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
    ENUM_WANT_SVALUE();

    if (RTEST(rb_yield(i))) {
        rb_ary_push(ary, i);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

The iterator used in `map`:

```
static VALUE
collect_i(VALUE i, VALUE ary, int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
    rb_ary_push(ary, enum_yield(argc, argv));

    return Qnil;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `ENUM_WANT_SVALUE()` macro is used to turn the value passed into the block into a splat array value (as opposed to a tuple with the latter arguments silently ignored). That said, I don't know why it was designed this way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see MRI source in [enum.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/7ea675732ac1dac72f07756498706678d8725719/enum.c). As @PlatinumAzure said,  the magic happens in `ENUM_WANT_SVALUE()`:

```
static VALUE
find_all_i(VALUE i, VALUE ary, int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
    ENUM_WANT_SVALUE();

    if (RTEST(rb_yield(i))) {
        rb_ary_push(ary, i);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

And we can find this macro actually is: `do {i = rb_enum_values_pack(argc, argv);}while(0)`.

So Let's continue dive into `rb_enum_values_pack` function:

```
VALUE
rb_enum_values_pack(int argc, VALUE *argv)
{
    if (argc == 0) return Qnil;
    if (argc == 1) return argv[0];
    return rb_ary_new4(argc, argv);
}
```

See? The arguments are packed by `rb_ary_new4`, which is defined in [array.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L451).